# Update a column based on a condition and groupby

Tags: r, dplyr

My data is:

```
Prod   Vend    Capac  Dema   Price
 p1     v2       2      6      1
 p1     v1       3      6      2
 p1     v3       3      6      2
 p2     v1       1      1      1
 p2     v3       2      1      2
 p2     v2       5      1      2
 p3     v1       5      3      3
 p3     v2       3      3      4
 p3     v3       1      3      5
```

And I require something like:

```
Prod   Vend    Capac  Dema   Price   Source
 p1     v2       2      6      1       2
 p1     v1       3      6      2       3
 p1     v3       3      6      2       1 
 p2     v1       1      1      1       1
 p2     v3       2      1      2       0
 p2     v2       5      1      2       0
 p3     v1       5      3      3       3
 p3     v2       3      3      4       0 
 p3     v3       1      3      5       0
```

i have product, vendor, capacity (of vendor), demand (of product), price (of product from vendor). I am sourcing the products based on least price but vendor capacity is a constraint. That is, the selection of a vendor is done by price it has quoted, Price is sorted for the vendors grouped by products.

I am trying it with for loop and if else conditions, the code is getting messier. Is there a clean way to solve it, probably using plyr?

Comment: Please describe (in words) what you want to do

Comment: What on earth is the logic to create the source column ???

Comment: Should there be no difference in choosing two vendors when they both have the same price? How do you break ties if necessary?

Comment: have edited my question,it would be the first one,no constraints on that.

Comment: It's still unclear to me why p3 v2 and p2 v2 have 0 as source ... (nor what source is in fact)

Comment: Tens bc the demand has been met already for that product

Comment: For product 2, the demand is `1`. The first vendor met that capacity. There is no need to get anything from the other vendors for that product.

Comment: @Tensibai because the demands are met,so i dont need vendor v2 for p3  and vendor v2 for product p2...hope this helps

Comment: It does absolutely not help me to understand, how and why is there a relation between product p1 and its 'best' vendor and product p3 for the same vendor ???, morever, then why is there a source for product p1 and vendor v1 and v3 ??? The realtion is absolutely unclear, try to explain me in the Q how the slection is done for a specific product for example (where does come 2 3 and 1 for p1 ?

Comment: Ok I think I got it: source is demand - capacity of vendor per product ? right ?

Comment: @VishalGupta If that is case then why the source for P3 is 3? shouldn't it be 1??

Comment: @VeerendraGadekar sir my demand for product p3 is 3 and vendor V1 has least price,i would source it from him..:)

Comment: @VishalGupta Is your original dataset already sorted by product and vendor price as your example ?

Comment: @VishalGupta if you source from him then the source should be 1 (v1) right? how do you define source? what are the numbers under source column correspond to?

Comment: Veerendra the Demand for product 3 is `3`. Why would it be `1`? three is the correct number. The question started vague but the logic does make sense.

Comment: @VeerendraGadekar see my previous comment, `source = Capa` as long as `Dema > 0`, by product and by row...

Comment: @Tensibai  yes sir

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's what I would do:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DT)

DT[order(Price), src := pmin(Capac, pmax(Dema - shift(cumsum(Capac), fill=0), 0)), by=Prod]
```

we can see it matches:

```
   Prod Vend Capac Dema Price Source src
1:   p1   v2     2    6     1      2   2
2:   p1   v1     3    6     2      3   3
3:   p1   v3     3    6     2      1   1
4:   p2   v1     1    1     1      1   1
5:   p2   v3     2    1     2      0   0
6:   p2   v2     5    1     2      0   0
7:   p3   v1     5    3     3      3   3
8:   p3   v2     3    3     4      0   0
9:   p3   v3     1    3     5      0   0
```

The logic, partly in pseudocode:

- `shift(cumsum(Capac), fill=0)` is capacity from cheaper vendors
- `max(demand - capacity from cheaper, 0)` is residual demand for the vendor
- `min(capacity, residual demand)` is how much to source from the vendor

.

---

The dplyr analogue:

```
DT %>% arrange(Price) %>% group_by(Prod) %>% 
  mutate(src = pmin(Capac, pmax(Dema - lag(cumsum(Capac), default=0), 0)))
```

Comment: Great clean approach. +2 for this