# For loop / replace value based on cumulative multiples contraints / groups

Tags: r, for-loop, data.table, dplyr

Following my previous question which was not clear for anyone. I come up with a new reproducible example

I have the following INPUT dataframe in R

```
DF.IN <- data.frame(
  "Product"= c("X1","X2","X3","X4","X5","X6"),
  "G1"= c("RC1","RC1","RC2","RC2","RC1","RC1"),
  "G2"= c("IN1","IN2","IN1","IN1","IN1","IN2"),
  "MAX.G1"= c("18","18","8","8","18","18"),
  "MAX.G2"= c("20","60","20","20","20","60"),
  "Amount"= c("10","5","3","6","15","1"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  )
```

which give

```
  Product  G1  G2 MAX.G1 MAX.G2 Amount
  X1       RC1 IN1  18     20     10
  X2       RC1 IN2  18     60      5
  X3       RC2 IN1   8     20      3
  X4       RC2 IN1   8     20      6
  X5       RC1 IN1  18     20     15
  X6       RC1 IN2  18     60      1
```

where

- G1 and G2 = Group 1 & Group 2
- Max.G1 and Max.G2 = Max amount allow for G1 and G2 respectively

If we calculate the Cumulative Amount for each group such as

```
DF.IN[, CumSum.G1 := cumsum(Amount), by = list(G1)]
DF.IN[, CumSum.G2 := cumsum(Amount), by = list(G2)]
```

We'll have the following results

```
   Product  G1  G2 MAX.G1 MAX.G2 Amount CumSum.G1 CumSum.G2
    X1      RC1 IN1     18     20     10        10        10
    X2      RC1 IN2     18     60      5        15         5
    X3      RC2 IN1      8     20      3         3        13
    X4      RC2 IN1      8     20      6         9        19
    X5      RC1 IN1     18     20     15        30        34
    X6      RC1 IN2     18     60      1        31         6
```

What i'm looking for is 
- for each `product`- the relevant `Amount` in which the `Cumulative Amount`  respect the Maximum Amount allow for each group `G1` & `G2` in the same time

So the OUTPUT desired is something like this

```
   Product  G1  G2 MAX.G1 MAX.G2 Amount.EXPECTED CumSum.G1 CumSum.G2
     X1     RC1 IN1     18     20       10        10        10
     X2     RC1 IN2     18     60        5        15         5
     X3     RC2 IN1      8     20        3         3        13
     X4     RC2 IN1      8     20        5         8        18
     X5     RC1 IN1     18     20        2        17        20
     X6     RC1 IN2     18     60        0        17         5
```

Can someone help me out with this issue ? Thanks a lot !!

Comment: I made the correction :)

Comment: If the MAX.G1 is 18 why you can't have 18 for CumSum.G1 and only 17

Comment: @ akrun, Amount for X5 = 15 | Previous Cumulative Amount for G1 = 15 | Previous Cumulative Amount for G2 = 18. If we take 3, so the CumSum.G1 = 18 (15+3) and CumSum.G2 = 21 (18+3 which is > Max.G2 = 20 ). The Expected Amount should respect the both contraints MAX.G1 and MAX.G2 in the same time.

Comment: You're using data.table syntax on a data.frame..?!?

Comment: @ akrun, the following code allows me to use data.table syntax : DF.IN <- data.table(DF.IN) :)

Comment: Some `pmin`, `pmax` and `shift` might help. I couldn't figure out how to do it cleanly, but here's a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35918851/

Comment: Hi Franck, thanks for your reply :) I already tested the kind of solution you mentionned. But the thing is if we use  the data.table syntax with "by = list(Group1, Group2,...GroupN)" or just " by = list(Group1)", we don't get the solution i'm looking for.